# Create a surface mesh using CGAL's Delaunay in 3D space with points as input

Tags: cgal, delaunay

I want to create a surface mesh using CGAL's Delaunay in 3D space with points as input.

Right now I have got a working version of 3D Delaunay from CGAL, but now I want to only return a surface from this result. I found this:

```
Surface_mesh_complex_2_in_triangulation_3<Delaunay>
```

Supposedly I would be able to input my delaunay result in the above mentioned Surface Mesh constructor, but I do not know where to go from that point on.

I have also read about Poisson Surface Reconstruction, but I want my input points also to be in my output; I just want the triangles from the delaunay result.

main.cpp

```
// test vector
std::vector<glm::vec3> l_Vec = { glm::vec3( -10,-10,-10 ), glm::vec3( -10,-10,10 ),glm::vec3( -10,10,-10 ),glm::vec3( -10,10,10 ),glm::vec3( 0,0,0 ), glm::vec3( 10,-10,-10 ), glm::vec3( 10,-10,10 ),glm::vec3( 10,10,-10 ),glm::vec3( 10,10,10 ) };
clsDelaunay3D l_Delaunay;
l_Delaunay.Triangulate( l_Vec );
SurfaceMesh sm( l_Delaunay.GetTriangulation( ) );
// what to do next?
```

clsDelaunay3D.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx_CGAL.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace GenerationLib
{
template<class GT, class Vb = CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<GT>>
class My_vertex_base : public Vb
{
public:
    typedef typename Vb::Vertex_handle  Vertex_handle;
    typedef typename Vb::Point          Point;
    typedef typename Vb::Cell_handle    Cell_handle;

    template<class TDS2>
    struct Rebind_TDS
    {
        typedef typename Vb::template Rebind_TDS<TDS2>::Other   Vb2;
        typedef My_vertex_base<GT, Vb2>                         Other;
    };

    My_vertex_base( )
    {
    }

    My_vertex_base( const Point&p ) : Vb( p )
    {
    }

    My_vertex_base( const Point&p, Cell_handle c ) : Vb( p, c )
    {
    }

    Vertex_handle vh;
    Cell_handle ch;
};

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<My_vertex_base<K>> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K, Tds> Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef Delaunay::Point Point;

typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_complex_2_in_triangulation_3<Delaunay> SurfaceMesh;

class clsDelaunay3D
{
public:
    clsDelaunay3D( );
    ~clsDelaunay3D( );
    void Init( );
    void AddPoint( glm::vec3 Position );
    void Triangulate( std::vector<glm::vec3> Points );
    Delaunay::All_vertices_iterator GetAllVerticesIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::All_vertices_iterator GetAllVerticesIteratorEnd( );
    Delaunay::Finite_vertices_iterator GetOuterVerticesIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::Finite_vertices_iterator GetOuterVerticesIteratorEnd( );

    Delaunay::All_edges_iterator GetAllEdgesIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::All_edges_iterator GetAllEdgesIteratorEnd( );
    Delaunay::Finite_edges_iterator GetOuterEdgesIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::Finite_edges_iterator GetOuterEdgesIteratorEnd( );

    Delaunay::All_facets_iterator GetAllFacetsIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::All_facets_iterator GetAllFacetsIteratorEnd( );
    Delaunay::Finite_facets_iterator GetOuterFacetsIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::Finite_facets_iterator GetOuterFacetsIteratorEnd( );

    Delaunay::All_cells_iterator GetAllCellsIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::All_cells_iterator GetAllCellsIteratorEnd( );
    Delaunay::Finite_cells_iterator GetOuterCellsIteratorBegin( );
    Delaunay::Finite_cells_iterator GetOuterCellsIteratorEnd( );

    Delaunay GetTriangulation( );

    void Destroy( );
private:
    Delaunay m_Triangulation;
};
}
```

clsDelaunay3D.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx_CGAL.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "clsDelaunay3D.h"

namespace GenerationLib
{
clsDelaunay3D::clsDelaunay3D( )
{

}

clsDelaunay3D::~clsDelaunay3D( )
{

}

void clsDelaunay3D::Init( )
{

}

void clsDelaunay3D::AddPoint( glm::vec3 a_Position )
{
    Vertex_handle vertex = m_Triangulation.insert( Point( a_Position.x, a_Position.y, a_Position.z ) );
}

void clsDelaunay3D::Triangulate( std::vector<glm::vec3> a_Points )
{
    std::vector<Point> l_DelPoints;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a_Points.size( ); ++i)
    {
        l_DelPoints.push_back( Point( a_Points[ i ].x, a_Points[ i ].y, a_Points[ i ].z ) );
    }
    m_Triangulation.insert( l_DelPoints.begin( ), l_DelPoints.end( ) );
}

Delaunay::All_vertices_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllVerticesIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_vertices_begin( );
}

Delaunay::All_vertices_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllVerticesIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_vertices_end( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_vertices_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterVerticesIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_vertices_begin( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_vertices_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterVerticesIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_vertices_end( );
}

Delaunay::All_edges_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllEdgesIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_edges_begin( );
}

Delaunay::All_edges_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllEdgesIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_edges_end( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_edges_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterEdgesIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_edges_begin( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_edges_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterEdgesIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_edges_end( );
}

Delaunay::All_facets_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllFacetsIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_facets_begin( );
}

Delaunay::All_facets_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllFacetsIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_facets_end( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_facets_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterFacetsIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_facets_begin( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_facets_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterFacetsIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_facets_end( );
}

Delaunay::All_cells_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllCellsIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_cells_begin( );
}

Delaunay::All_cells_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetAllCellsIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.all_cells_end( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_cells_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterCellsIteratorBegin( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_cells_begin( );
}

Delaunay::Finite_cells_iterator clsDelaunay3D::GetOuterCellsIteratorEnd( )
{
    return m_Triangulation.finite_cells_end( );
}

Delaunay clsDelaunay3D::GetTriangulation( )
{
    return m_Triangulation;
}

void clsDelaunay3D::Destroy( )
{

}
}
```

If anyone has a better way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the Delaunay triangulation you should use [surface reconstruction algorithms](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PartReconstruction)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't think that is what I am looking for. I will only have a few points to triangulate (about 5 - 10) in 3D space. Also, my initial idea was wrong, as I don't need 3D triangulation, but 2D triangulation in 3D space. so imagine a 2D Delaunay triangulation, but now with the z axis added. I hope you understand what I mean, is this possible with CGAL?

Comment: As you describe it maybe this example does the job: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title14

Comment: Is it possible to build a closed 3D object with this aswell, as normally terrain is open at the bottom. For example, if I have 10 points on the surface of a sphere, I want to connect these points together to create a closed (spherical) shape, but without any connections inside the object (surface only).

Comment: I am tempted to write  "Use `triangulate_hole()`, but that may lead to a self-intersecting surface: Imagine your terrain has a circular boundary in the xy-plane, and you have a sub-sea area and a mountain.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. For Delaunay Surface Triangulation, is it possible to set the projection traits to any plane? I have noticed that CGAL supports xy, yz and xz axes, but how does that work with a 3D spherical object? Example: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWkjH.png)        Looking at the left most image, that is the result of a surface triangulation that I want if I were to input the 6 points of that object into my Delaunay Surface Triangulation